# Better alternative to alpine rootfs

Tags: bash, package-management, root-filesystem, alpine-linux

I am using Alpine linux rootfs for playing with namespaces. But, I am running into a major issue - Bash is no available as part of the minimal root filesystem. "Busybox bash" does not work either. I am running a Ubuntu virutal machine, and `apk update` or `apk fetch bash` don't seem to work either.

Would anyone have any pointers to an alternative rootfs or how to get bash installed on the minimal rootfs please?  I would greatly appreciate some help.

EDIT: Based on the comment below, adding more details so this is more visible.

Though I am using a Ubuntu VM, I am using Apline Linux minimal rootfs to better understand Namespaces.

When I use Alpine rootfs as the new root  (using `pivot_root`), the new environment created has no Bash. To add any software to Alpline rootfs (inside my Ubuntu VM), I need to use `apk` (Apline Package Keeper), but this is where I am running into issues - `apk update` or `apk fetch bash` always fails.

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't use `apk`, it uses `apt`. Use `apt update; apt install bash`. How minimal is minimal?

Comment: @icarus - Please see "Minimal Root FileSystem" here - https://alpinelinux.org/downloads/

Comment: With respect, pointing to an Alpine web page to download a "minimal" root filesystem doesn't answer the question "How minimal is minimal?". What are you going to use the image for? `go` programs are typically self contained and so you can often use a `scratch` container or else augment a scratch container with a set of SSL certificates if all you want to do is run a go binary. If you want to be able to run a webserver written in python, then your minimal container is a lot bigger. You say you have a Ubuntu VM, what do you want to subract from it and what do you want to add?

Comment: @icarus Thank You for the follow-up and I apologize. Did not mean any disrespect. I was just trying to convey what I was trying out. Anyway, it appears I have been able to resolve the issue. To summarize, I was using this Minimal Root FS provided by Alpine to play with "pivot_root" and the unshare system calls. What I was running into was that rootfs did not have bash, which gave me some trouble. I found out that the rootfs provided by Alpine did not include any network settings. Adding those to /etc and running 'apk update' from within the rootfs resolved the problem of installing bash.

Comment: Hello @user1689430 I am running into the same issue. Would you mind providing the commands you used to add those to /etc? Apologies for the dumb question as I am quite new to Linux